# Trigger a closing function in mmenu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I've been trying to create a button that animates when the menu opens and closes. To do this I created a simple function to execute `API.open();` and `API.close();` when the button is clicked. Code:

```
var API = $("#primary-menu").data( "mmenu" ),
      menuOpen = 0;

  $("#menu-button").click(function() {
    if(menuOpen === 0){
      API.open();
      menuOpen = 1;
    }
    else{
      API.close();
      menuOpen = 0;
    }
  });
```

Now the problem is the button doesn't animate when the menu closes by clicking on the content area

```
$(".mm-opening #mm-0").click(function(){
    console.log("Click Successful");
    $("#menu-button").removeClass("close");
  });
```

Using the console.log method and dev tools, I found out the the click is not at all registered when I click in the content area, so I cannot animate the icon.

Here's the demo: http://bwdmedia.in/camelport/vendor-panel/
Can someone explain the reason for this? Or another way to achieve the same result.

Comment: I think a good solution would be if someone could go through `jquery.mmenu.min.js` file and figure out where exactly is the code located that triggers the open and close of the menu. I went through it but couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to the GitHub community, I found the solution.

There's a `div` with id `#mm-blocker` which prevents interaction with the page so I turned it off with `display:none;` and the clicks can be registered by javascript now.

Answer (score 2):

You could get an animated Hamburger added by following the steps mentioned below

**The icon**

First, head on over to this amazing collection of animated hamburger icons, download the CSS and follow the instructions. You should now have HTML looking something like this:

```
<button id="my-icon" class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
   <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
   </span>
</button>
```

If you need your hamburger icon to be fixed, try wrapping it in a DIV and use the fixedElements add-on.

```
<div class="Fixed">
   <button id="my-icon" class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
         <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
   </button>
</div>
```

**The menu**

Second (and last), create the menu and use the API to open the menu and to animate the icon. Add a small timeout to ensure the rest of the page is finished animating for a smoother animation.

```
var $menu = $("#my-menu").mmenu({
   //   options
});
var $icon = $("#my-icon");
var API = $menu.data( "mmenu" );

$icon.on( "click", function() {
   API.open();
});

API.bind( "open:finish", function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $icon.addClass( "is-active" );
   }, 100);
});
API.bind( "close:finish", function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $icon.removeClass( "is-active" );
   }, 100);
});
```

http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/animated-hamburger.html

Answer (score 0):

mmenu add a class on html tag `.mm-opened` when menu is triggered and remove it when its close, so you can set a interval to watch if html tag has this class

if you are using JQuery you can do something like this.

```
var thread = setInterval(checkHtmlTag(),20)

    function checkHtmlTag (){
     var menuOpen;

     if ($("html").hasClass("mm-opened")){
      menuOpen = true
     } else{
       menuOpen = false
       }
    }
```